# Vuetify/Vue 2 - Force a v-card to always be square, but resize dynamically

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, aspect-ratio

The issue I'm running into is I'm trying to enforce a v-card to always remain a square (or really, whatever aspect ratio I've set), even if it means scrolling or cutting off text/components inside that v-card.

Example: I want this v-card with the lorem ipsum text to always be the same size as the square cards being displayed, but just allowing scrolling instead (or even just cutting off the text would be a good start).

The v-img is being used to stretch that v-card to the square size when there isn't enough content to do so, not sure if something else could be used here?
[image]

Here is the code being used for displaying the card in v-row for loop:

```
  <v-card width="100%"
          aspect-ratio="1"
          :color="text ? 'primary' : ''">
      <v-img aspect-ratio="1">
        <v-card-text class="text-h6 font-weight-black white--text">
          {{ text }}
        </v-card-text>
      </v-img>
  </v-card>
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What is the use of `v-img`, I see you don't give it a `src` attribute?

Comment: have you tried `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: The use of v-img is a bit hacky, it's enforcing that the v-card sits open to that aspect ratio. Without it the v-card collapses to it's minimum height. I don't really want to define a min or max height as I would like that to change dynamically to fit the space available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for [this](https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/JjLNYWv)

you need to set height width dynamic using calc or something else

```
<v-row>
    <template v-for="i in 10" >
      <v-col sm="3" lg="6" md="4">
    <v-card :key="i"
            class="ma-2 pt-2"
            outlined
            style="overflow-y:scroll;
                   height: 250px"
          aspect-ratio="1" 
          :color="text ? 'primary' : ''">
      <v-img aspect-ratio="1">
        <v-card-text >
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

        </v-card-text>
      </v-img>
  </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
```

Comment: The problem I have with this is that when resizing the screen, the cards don't grow dynamically to fill space.

I know I can set up a calculation function to return specific heights and widths based on if the viewport is mobile, tablet, laptop, desktop, etc, but I was hoping there was a simpler way. It seems as though aspect-ratio should work in such a way that the 'thing' the aspect ratio is being placed on should do those calculations for you.

Comment: hi i edited the answer is this work for you or are you looking for something else!

Comment: Ah - yes. That seems like what I was trying to do!

Comment: ok, that sounds good!